# Redefining a callable object during Run Time

Tags: python, python-2.7, callable

I using the wx library to build a GUI. I have initialized a panel and intialized some push buttons and have binded a function that will execute when pushed. The function takes a list of arguments, one which is a callback function. What I am trying to do is redefine the callback function during runtime but I am failing to do so.

My attempt so far is:

```
    self.UpdateCurrent = None
    self.GetCurrent = None
    self.UpdateCellVoltage = None
    self.GetCellVoltage = None
    self.UpdateCellTemperature = None
    self.GetCellTemperature = None
    self.battery_control_d = OrderedDict([('Current',[self.UpdateCurrent, self.GetCurrent, None, 1]),
                                          ('Cell Voltage',[self.UpdateCellVoltage, self.GetCellVoltage, 0, 24]),
                                          ('Cell Temperature',[self.UpdateCellTemperature, self.GetCellTemperature, 0, 24])])
    .
    .
    .
    submit_btn_l[-1].Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,
                          lambda evt,
                          io_name = io_name,
                          callback_fn = self.battery_control_d[io_name][0],
                          ctrl_textbox = ctrl_textbox,
                          dim_combobox = self.dim_combobox_l[-1]:
                          self._send_control_value(evt,
                                                   io_name,
                                                   callback_fn,
                                                   ctrl_textbox,
                                                   dim_combobox))
    .
    .
    .
    def init_battery_intf(self):
        self.battery_intf = self.simulator_main_panel.battery_intf

        self.UpdateCurrent = self.battery_intf.UpdateCurrent
        self.GetCurrent = self.battery_intf.GetCurrent

        self.UpdateCellVoltage = self.battery_intf.UpdateCellVoltage
        self.GetCellVoltage = self.battery_intf.GetCellVoltage

        self.UpdateCellTemperature = self.battery_intf.UpdateCellTemperature
        self.GetCellTemperature = self.battery_intf.GetCellTemperature
    .
    .
    .
    def _send_control_value(self,
                            evt,
                            io_name,
                            callback_fn,
                            ctrl_textbox,
                            dim_combobox):
        io_value = float(ctrl_textbox.Value)
        if ("Temperature" in io_name):
            io_value -= self.simulator_main_gui.temperature_unit_converter
        callback_fn(io_value, int(dim_combobox.Value))
    def update( self,
                evt ):

        for io_name, io_info in self.battery_control_d.iteritems():
            io_value = float(io_info[1](io_info[2]))

            self.reading_text_l[self.io_indexer.index(io_name)].SetLabel(" %.4f " % (io_value))
```

I predefine some update/get objects.

I bind the function to the buttons

During runtime I call init_battery_intf to initialize these objects

The line that errors out is when I try to call the callback function. It seems to be still be set to None.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\work\simulator\src\simulate.py", line 1185, in updat
    self.control_notebook.update(evt)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\work\simulator\src\simulate.py", line 869, in update
    self.battery_control_panel.update(evt)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\work\simulator\src\simulate.py", line 591, in update
    io_value = float(io_info[1](io_info[2]))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I know I could redefine the bind and feed in the values directly, but I wanted to keep my code clean and simple, and I feel like Python has a way to distribute the redefined callback function to all instances of the object.

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: please show the entire traceback, it really helps in knowing what lines in the code are resulting in a problem.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Added Tracelog and the function where the error  occurs.

Comment: Is `io_info[1]` what you expect to be a callback function?  That is the expression that evaluates to `None` and can't be called.

Comment: ahh, I see what is happening you are storing `self.UpdateCurrent` (and others) in a dictionary `self.battery_control_d` **before** they are changed from `None` to callable things.  Python does not store a reference as "when accessing this part of the dict get the attribute from self" it just stores the value at the time which is None.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Is there a trick I can do so the callback is stored by reference? So when I update the callback it'll update through all its instances?

Comment: @dsh Yes Dsh, io_info is the value of the self.batter_control_d and inside the index 0 should be a callback function. The problem is, it doesn't seem to be a reference so when I update the callback function (self.UpdateCurrent) it won't be updated in the function properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

A: Have `self.UpdateCurrent` and the other methods used by `self.battery_control_d` already initialized. (never initialize to None)

B: when `self.UpdateCurrent` and/or the others are updated recreate/update `self.battery_control_d`.

C: Use a name reference and get the value of that attribute when accessed from `self.battery_control_d`.

---

The first two are pretty self explanatory but it seems you are interested in option C so I will expand on it:

You can create a class with several `property`(ies) that retrieve an attribute from your original object when accessed.

```
class VarReference(object):
    def __init__(self, inst, update_name, get_name, value1, value2):
        self.inst = inst
        self.update_attr_name = update_name
        self.getter_attr_name = get_name
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    @property
    def get(self):
        return getattr(self.inst, self.getter_attr_name)

    @property
    def update(self):
        return getattr(self.inst, self.update_attr_name)


class Test(object):pass #dummy class for my demo
self = Test()

self.UpdateCurrent = self.GetCurrent = None

ref_obj = VarReference(self,"UpdateCurrent","GetCurrent",None,1)

>>> print(ref_obj.get)
None
>>> self.GetCurrent = lambda:5
>>> ref_obj.get
<function <lambda> at 0x1057d5488>
>>> ref_obj.get()
5
```

If you are unfamiliar with `property` basically the function that it decorates is called when the attribute name is accessed on an instance (and therefore retrieving an attribute of the original instance)

so you would in this case write the initialization for `self.battery_control_d` like this:

```
self.battery_control_d = OrderedDict([('Current',VarReference(self, "UpdateCurrent", "GetCurrent", None, 1)),
                                      ('Cell Voltage',VarReference(self, "UpdateCellVoltage", "GetCellVoltage", 0, 24)),
                                      ('Cell Temperature',VarReference(self, "UpdateCellTemperature", "GetCellTemperature", 0, 24))
                                    ])
```

then `self.battery_control_d["current"].get` would be the result of `getattr(self,"GetCurrent")` which is equivalent to `self.GetCurrent` dynamically.

If you really want to use `VALUE[0]` and `VALUE[1]` instead of `VALUE.update` and `VALUE.get` then you can just override `__getitem__` of the class as well, although I'd highly recommend switching to more verbose solutions:

```
class VarReference(object):
    ...   
    def __getitem__(self,item):
        if item==0:
            return self.update
        elif item == 1:
            return self.get
        elif item ==2:
            return self.value1
        elif item == 3:
            return self.value2
        else:
            raise IndexError("Can only get indices from 0 to 3")
```

Comment: I'd also like to add that making properties that simply **call the Get function** and have setters that call the update would make a lot of sense here, although your get function seems to take an argument so I'm not really sure how it would fit into your implementation.

Comment: Thank you very very much. Been stuck on this for a while, and it seems Property was the key concept I was missing. Very cool trick/tool.

As for my functions taking arguments it seems when I call Instance of VarReference Method Get, you can feed in arguments into its signature if it is a function that has any signatures.

ref_get.get(arg1, arg2, arg3 ...). Maybe you could edit your answer to include that so it can be a complete solution. I tested it out by passing a simple function.

Comment: my understanding was that you wanted a way to dynamically retrieve the value of `self.UpdateCurrent` and `self.GetCurrent` which I have provided.  when you do `ref_Var.get` it gets the method (callable or not) from self and then you call it as if writing `self.GetCurrent(ARG)`.  If your getter took no arguments and the update took a single argument you could have the property called `value` which calls the getter method so that you can just do `ref_var.value` to get the value and `ref_var.value = NEW_VALUE` to update it.